Asymptotic expansion of a logarithmicaly divergent integral $\underset{-\pi/2}{\overset{\pi/2}{\int}}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\cos\alpha\cos\phi}}$
I am interested in the asymptotic expansion in the parameter $\alpha$ for integrals of the form,
$$J\left(\alpha\right)=\underset{-\pi/2}{\overset{\pi/2}{\int}}d\phi\frac{I\left(\phi\right)}{\sqrt{1-\cos\alpha\cos\phi}}$$
Assuming $I\left(\phi\right)$ is a "nice" function in the domain of integration such that the integral converges.
For $I\left(\phi\right)=1$, Mathematica manages to do the integration, and it appears that the leading behavior at $\alpha\rightarrow 0$ is,
$$\underset{-\pi/2}{\overset{\pi/2}{\int}}d\phi\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos\alpha\cos\phi}}=c_{0}\log\alpha+c_{1}+c_{2}\alpha^{2}\log\alpha+\dots$$
I am interested in finding the leading coefficient $c_0$ for the general case which is the integral $J\left(\alpha\right)$. I recon it depends on $I\left(0\right)$ or something like that.
Your help will be very much appreciated.
Many thanks! :)

Here are some ideas: 1) If you remove a neighborhood of 0 in the integration domain, then $J(0)$ is a finite constante 2) If you think about showing that the integral is absolutely convergent when $\alpha =0$, it seems reasonable to ask for $I$ to vanish around $\phi =0$. Try to state and prove such a statement, maybe $I(0) = I’(0) =0$ is enough 3) For a general $I$, tune it so as it matches the conditions of the previous point

$c_0=2\sqrt2, I(0)$

Thanks! I will have a look.

@Svyatoslav Perhaps $c_0=-2\sqrt{2}, I(0)$?

@Gary, yes, of course. Thank you!

Let $a=\cos(\alpha)$
$$I=\int \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-a \cos (\phi )}}=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{1-a}}F\left(\frac{\phi }{2}|\frac{2 a}{a-1}\right)$$
$$J=\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-a \cos (\phi )}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-a}}F\left(\frac{\pi }{4}|\frac{2 a}{a-1}\right)$$Replace $a$ by $\cos(\alpha)$
$$J=\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-\cos (\alpha )}}F\left(\frac{\pi }{4}|-\frac{2 \cos (\alpha )}{1-\cos (\alpha )}\right)$$ which could be further simplified.
Expanded as series
$$J=\sqrt{2} \log \left(\frac{128}{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^2}\right)-2 \sqrt{2}\, \log (\alpha )+$$ $$\frac{6 \sqrt{2}+63 \log (2)-14-18 \log \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}{24 \sqrt{2}}\,\alpha^2-\frac{3 }{4 \sqrt{2}}\,\alpha ^2\, \log (\alpha )+\cdots$$

Thanks for your notes and time! This is a very nice direction. Now I need to see how to incorporate $I(\phi)$ into the picture.

@T.Math It follows from this result that $$
\int_{ - \pi /2}^{\pi /2} {\frac{{I(\phi )}}{{\sqrt {1 - \cos \alpha \cos \phi } }}{\rm d}\phi }  =  - 2\sqrt 2, I(0)\log |\alpha|  + \mathcal{O}(1) + \int_{ - \pi /2}^{\pi /2} {\frac{{I(\phi ) - I(0)}}{{\sqrt {1 - \cos \alpha \cos \phi } }}{\rm d}\phi } .
$$ Now if $I$ is sufficiently nice, the last integral is bounded as $\alpha\to 0$. (For instance, if $I$ has a bounded derivative.)

I see, thank you very much!
